# JSR223 PreProccesser script not working - jmeter

Tags: selenium, groovy, jmeter

I have a groovy script where im trying to collect the cookie to use in another http request. I can grab the cookie with the below

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('mywebsite')
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.linkText("Login")).click();
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id("username")).sendKeys("username");
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id("password")).sendKeys("password");
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).click();
java.lang.Thread.sleep(5000)
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Skip for now')]")).click();
var cookies = WDS.browser.manage().getCookies()
WDS.vars.putObject('cookies', cookies);
java.lang.Thread.sleep(5000)
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

and in the debug listner i can see the cookie but when i try to pass the cookie to my http request im using the below script

```
 def cookies = vars.getObject('cookies')
log.info('cookies=' + cookies)
cookies.collect { cookie ->
    new org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie(cookie.getName(),
            cookie.getValue(),
            cookie.getDomain(),
            cookie.getPath(),
            cookie.isSecure(),
            cookie.getExpiry().getTime())
}.each { cookie -> sampler.getCookieManager().add(cookie) }
```

when i run it i get the below error

JSR223PreProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PreProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getTime() on null object

any idea on how i can resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one or more of your cookies do not have an expiry set.

Also even if they do have the expiry set, the `cookie.getExpiry()` call returns a `java.util.Date` and the `getTime` call returns the time in milliseconds since 1970 (epoch time) whereas the [jmeter cookie constructor](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/control/Cookie.html#Cookie-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-boolean-long-) expects the expiry time in epoch seconds, not milliseconds.

You could do something like this:

```
cookies.collect { cookie ->
  def defaultExpiry = System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000 //10 seconds from now
  
  new org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie(cookie.getName(),
            cookie.getValue(),
            cookie.getDomain(),
            cookie.getPath(),
            cookie.isSecure(),
            (cookie.getExpiry()?.getTime() ?: defaultExpiry) / 1000.0)
  ...
```

where the "safe navigation" operator `?.` means "don't throw null pointer exception if getExpiry() returns null, just return null instead" and the elvis operator `?:` means "if the expression on the left is 'truthy' (i.e. not null or empty), use it, otherwise use the `defaultExpiry` on the right.

Should be noted that this was written totally off the cuff, is untested etc and you might need to tweak things, but you get the general idea.

Comment: i have been playing with this and unfortunately i cannot get this to work. It just seems no matter what i try jmeter will not record the cookie as a variable. It shows in the response but not the request